# It is threads versus they are threads

Tags: grammar

I don't understand why the author used "It is" rather than `They are` in the following sentence.

> **It is** threads, not processes, that are the units scheduled by the
>   system for execution on the processor.

Why don't we say the following?

> They **are** threads, not processes, that are the units scheduled by the
>   system for execution on the processor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [cleft sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence): "It is *noun phrase* that *clause*." In this construct, the pronoun is always "it"; it doesn't agree with the number (or gender) of anything. So it doesn't matter that *threads* or *are* are plural.

Comment: I agree with this answer, and a cleft sentence is one type of use of [dummy pronouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun). I think the only dummy pronouns in English are "it", "there", and the "wh-" relative pronouns, but never "they".

Answer (score 2):

I would say that "It is" is definitely correct because "they are" totally changes the meaning. But I am struggling to say why.

The problem really is the use of the plural "threads". So a better version might be:

> It is the thread, not the process, that is the unit scheduled ...

But that loses the fact that there are multiple threads that are scheduled.

Better:

> It is the set of threads, not processes, that provide the units scheduled ...

So maybe we should consider that "threads" is being used as an uncountable noun (for the *concept* of threads) that just happens to look like a plural.

Comment: *It is oranges I like, not apples*. That is *clearly* plural, and yet the singular verb makes sense. (The subject is *it*, not the plural things.) In this case, I think that the singular can apply, regardless of the plurality of the object. I believe it's a dummy pronoun, as in *it is raining*. We could also say *it is many small things that can drive somebody to distraction.*